# How to output query(mysql) data on a pdf file using TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

The code below is in PHP. How do I use TCPDF to output the query data in a .pdf file?

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("ef_kabaadkhana");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ef_form_master_v1 where form_id='praxis0411'");
```

Comment: Here my solution. Look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802383/symfony-1-4-with-tcpdf-how-to-retreive-data-from-a-database-and-show-it-as-a-p

Answer (score 0):

The simple and immediate solution is to put your mysql data inside valid html using tables  and use the writehtml function from tcpdf.

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Store result array value to a string variable or make a HTML format. Then use the following code.

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
```